# How to get Jquery to Show/Hide Dynamic Div Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to use JQuery replicate the following javascript code so the page doesn't have to refresh. The main issue I'm having with Jquery is that the divs I want to select vary based on the comment id of which there could be hundreds. Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated!

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'visible';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
{% for comment in comments %}
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('make_reply_{{comment.id}}');">Reply</a>
<div id="make_reply_{{comment.id}}">
<form name="titleform" action="/{{slug}}/reply/" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{comment.id}}"</input>
{% csrf_token %}
<textarea name = "comment" value="" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

HIya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gpwnn/

API link: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**code**

```
toggle_visibility = function (id){

   var e = $("#"+id);
   e.toggle();
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, use [`$.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead:

```
$( '#' + id ).toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var $e = $('#' + id);
   if($e.is(':visible'))
      $e.hide();
   else
     $e.show();
}
```

or just `$e.toggle();`

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var $e = $('#' + id);
   $e.toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i had to do this,  i would it in much easier way like below:

**HTML:**

```
 {% for comment in comments %}
 <div id="{{comment.id}}"> // this div will separate each iterate elements
   <a href="#">Reply</a> // no inline method required in jquery
   <form name="titleform" action="/{{slug}}/reply/" method = "post">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{comment.id}}"/>
     <textarea name = "comment" value="" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

**jquery**

```
 $('a').click(function(){
   $(this).next('form').toggle();
 });
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/VjthL/2/